# Can pressure be subtracted from pressure gradient

Tags: pressure

I just want to know if the pressure can be subtracted from pressure gradient.    I did a google search and it didn't help me.

I know the question is silly and the answer to it should be no but at one place i read it can be subtracted so sorry if the question seems to be stupid and pls kindly help.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me: $P$ and $\nabla P$ don't have the same units, so they cannot be added...

Comment: ... in other words:  no you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot subtract a pressure from a pressure gradient because they have different dimensions. However suppose you express the pressure gradient as:

$$ \frac{dP}{dx} = \frac{P_1 - P_2}{x_1 - x_2} $$

then you can subtract some constant pressure $P_0$ from both $P_1$ and $P_2$:

$$\begin{align}
P'_1 &= P_1 - P_0 \\
P'_2 &= P_2 - P_0
\end{align}$$

and your pressure gradient will be unchanged i.e.

$$ \frac{dP}{dx} = \frac{P_1 - P_2}{x_1 - x_2} = \frac{P'_1 - P'_2}{x_1 - x_2} $$